# How to get the pointer to canvas for a custom view in a user defined function in android

Tags: android

I have an activity which extends view i.e. its a custom view.I want to get the pointer to the canvas in my own function to draw something instead of the overridden ondraw/draw methods.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `ondraw(Canvas canvas)` and don't call `super.ondraw()`. Call instead myCustomDraw(canvas) and draw to that canvas. That's the View's canvas